# React Native, useState does not seem to be setting the value

Tags: react-native, axios

I am running an axios get request and the value does not seem to be setting on the first try.

the weird thing is that it does set on the 2nd try.

I am pointing to the id.

the hook is

```
const [id, setId] = useState("");
```

on the first pass however, the Id is blank (you can see my comment)

Here is the axios request.

```
const setDevice = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setShowModal(false);
    try {
      console.log("trying")
      console.log("Serial Number is " + serialNumber)
      const response = await axios.get(
        url + serialNumber,
        {
          headers: { Authorization: authHeader },
        }
        
      );
      //This does not seem to be working
      setId(response.data.mobile_devices[0].id);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Failed");
      setError("Something went Wrong");
      setIsLoading(false);
      setShowModal(false);
      setShowErrorModal(true);
    }
    //because this is blank
    console.log("trying to put with id of " + id)
    await axios.put(
      url + id,
      body,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: authHeader,
          "Content-Type": "application/xml",
        },
      }
    );
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

This is the data that is in the get request

```
Object {
  "mobile_devices": Array [
    Object {
      "department": "",
      "department_name": "",
      "email": "",
      "email_address": "",
      "id": 1,
      "position": "",
      "realname": "",
      "room": "",
      "username": "",
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the state update performed with `setId(<some id>)` is async. Therefore you won't be able to access the newly set id immediately.

To handle such situations in which some code depends on the updated state, the [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) was introduced. It is called after your component is updated with the new state and accepts an array of dependencies (in your case this is the `id`).

In your case, you could use it like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // check that id is already set
    if (id) {
      axios.put(
        url + id,
        body,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: authHeader,
            "Content-Type": "application/xml",
          },
        }
      ).then(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }).catch(error => {
         //handle errors here if needed.
      })
    }
}, [id, setIsLoading]);
```

Note place this below your useState function (`const [id, setId] = useState("");`)

**UPDATE**

It turned out that the id wasn't needed in the state and the put request should be done when setDevice is called and not when the id changes. In this case the usage of the `useEffect` hook is unnecessary and the put request can just be done with the obtained `id`:

```js
const setDevice = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("url" + serialNumber, {
        headers: { Authorization: authHeader },
      });
      const id = response.data.mobile_devices[0].id;
      await axios.put(
          url + id,
          body,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: authHeader,
              "Content-Type": "application/xml",
            },
          }
        )
    } catch (err) {
      setError("Something went Wrong");
      setIsLoading(false);
      setShowModal(false);
      setShowErrorModal(true);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Humm. I understand what you are saying. But trying what you suggested is giving me a whole new set of problems. its not liking it all in the same function.

Comment: Where did you add the function? It should be directly in your react component like your useState calls. (not inside the `setDevice` function).  Also you might want to handle situations in which the id is not yet set. I'll update the answer to include that.

Comment: Also I've just noticed that the `useEffect` function needs to be either async or handle the promise directly. I've edited it in order to handle the promise directly. If you rather want to use an async function, you can just add the `async` keyword and await the result of the put request.

Comment: ok. that may be my problem. im trying to figure out where you put this. Since all the app does is take the data from 3 text inputs, then when you put a button it does the get request to grab the ID, then it does the put request. So I am not sure where I can put that in my component.

Comment: Ya,  I just get invalid Hook Call

Comment: Just put it directly below this line `const [id, setId] = useState("");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219222/discussion-between-bnd10706-and-leo).

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, unfortunately this behaviour is totally normal. In hooks, `setId` is async so is not guaranteed that on next line `id` contains the value setted in `setId`.

If you want to get `id` value every time this one is changing his value, you have to use `useEffect` hook. Something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log("this is the value of id: " + id);
}, [id]);
```

As you can see, I put `id` on `useEffect` deps list. That means that `useEffect` will be triggered every time you change `id` value.